# ESP32 CAM sends empty string sometimes while sending http request

Tags: http, arduino, esp32

In my recent project I'm trying sense motion and send it as a base64 string using HTTP(from esp32 cam) to google colab the problem is sometimes an empty string is sent and sometimes the base64 string is sent correctly. I'm new to this topic and my project is due next week please help me guys. Thanks in advance

CODE IN ESP32-CAM

````
#define VERBOSE#include "soc/soc.h" // Disable brownour problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h" // Disable brownour problems
#include <base64.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include "EloquentSurveillance.h"
#include "soc/soc.h" // Disable brownour problems
#include "soc/rtc_cntl_reg.h" // Disable brownour problems

/*
const char* ssid = "-----";
const char* password = "------";
*/

#define WIFI_SSID "----------"
#define WIFI_PASS "----------"

/**
 * Instantiate motion detector
 */

EloquentSurveillance::Motion motion;
//EloquentSurveillance::StreamServer streamServer(80);

/**
 *
 */
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    
    // WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    // Serial.println("Connecting");
    // while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    //   delay(500);
    //   Serial.print(".");
    // }
    // Serial.println("");
    // Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
    // Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    delay(3000);
    debug("INFO", "Init");

    /**
     * See CameraCaptureExample for more details
     */

    camera.aithinker();
    camera.vga();
    camera.bestQuality();

    /**
     * Configure motion detection
     *
     * > setMinChanges() accepts a number from 0 to 1 (percent) or an integer
     *   At least the given number of pixels must change from one frame to the next
     *   to trigger the motion.
     *   The following line translates to "Trigger motion if at least 10% of the pixels
     *   in the image changed value"
     */
    motion.setMinChanges(0.05);
    //motion.setMinChanges(0.02);

    /**
     * > setMinPixelDiff() accepts an integer
     *   Each pixel value must differ at least of the given amount from one frame to the next
     *   to be considered as different.
     *   The following line translates to "Consider a pixel as changed if its value increased
     *   or decreased by 10 (out of 255)"
     */
    //motion.setMinPixelDiff(5);
    motion.setMinPixelDiff(10);


    /**
     * > setMinSizeDiff() accepts a number from 0 to 1 (percent) or an integer
     *   To speed up the detection, you can exit early if the image size is almost the same.
     *   This is an heuristic that says: "If two consecutive frames have a similar size, they
     *   probably have the same contents". This is by no means guaranteed, but can dramatically
     *   reduce the computation cost.
     *   The following line translates to "Check for motion if the filesize of the current image
     *   differs by more than 5% from the previous".
     *
     *   If you don't feel like this heuristic works for you, delete this line.
     */
    //motion.setMinSizeDiff(0.015);
    //motion.setMinSizeDiff(0.02);
    motion.setMinSizeDiff(0.05);

    motion.debounce(5000L);
    

    /**
     * Initialize the camera
     * If something goes wrong, print the error message
     */
    while (!camera.begin())
        debug("ERROR", camera.getErrorMessage());

    debug("SUCCESS", "Camera OK");
      /**
     * Connect to WiFi
     * If something goes wrong, print the error message
     */
    while (!wifi.connect(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS))
        debug("ERROR", wifi.getErrorMessage());

 

    /**
     * Display address of stream server
     */
    //debug("SUCCESS", streamServer.getWelcomeMessage());
}

/**
 *
 */

void loop() {
    /**
     * Try to capture a frame
     * If something goes wrong, print the error message
     */
    if (!camera.capture()) {
        debug("ERROR", camera.getErrorMessage());
        return;
    }

    /**
     * Look for motion.
     * In the `true` branch, you can handle a motion event.
     * For the moment, just print the processing time for motion detection.
     */
    if (!motion.update())
        return;

    if (motion.detect()) {
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        debug("INFO", String("Motion detected in ") + motion.getExecutionTimeInMicros() + " us");
        //String encoded = base64::encode(camera.getBuffer(), camera.getFileSize());
        //int size = camera.getFileSize() + 50;
        HTTPClient http;
        //http.begin("http://192.168.1.38:8000/capture");
        http.begin("http://9793-34-125-220-222.ngrok-free.app/");
        int res_c = http.POST(base64::encode(camera.getBuffer(), camera.getFileSize()));
        //Serial.println(encoded.c_str());
        // if(res_c > 0){
        //   Serial.println(res_c);
        // }
        // else{
        //   Serial.println("Not sent");
        //   Serial.print(res_c);
        // }
        // http.end();
        
        }
        delay(4000);
    }
    else if (!motion.isOk()) {
        /**
         * Something went wrong.
         * This part requires proper handling if you want to integrate it in your project
         * because you can reach this point for a number of reason.
         * For the moment, just print the error message
         */
        debug("ERROR", motion.getErrorMessage());
    }
}```
````